# No instance (Integral Float) in div

Tags: haskell, types

I wanted to convert a Int to a float for a division that should result in an float.
Therefor I wanted to do the following: `(intToFloat w) 'div' 2.0` where

```
intToFloat :: Int -> Float
intToFloat x = fromIntegral x:: Float
```

But it will give me the error `No instance for (Integral Float) arising from a use of ‘div’`. Is there a way I can resolve this?

Comment: Typically you use `div` for Integral types and / (slash) for floating-point types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `intToFloat w / 2.0`

`div` is [integer division](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral).

`(/)` is [real division](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional).